# How to implement horizontal scrolling in box2d?

Tags: iphone, scroll, box2d, box2d-iphone

I'm working on an iPhone game using box2D and I need to implement horizontal scrolling... I was able to scroll the background textures and all... But, the problem is that, I'm not able to scroll the physics world of box2d... Please help me, how to move the box2d world... I'm not using cocos2d... I googled a lot, but was not able to find any solution without cocos2d...

Regards,

Suran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not move the world. Instead, try  moving the "camera" (clip area) accordingly with the game character.

Answer (score 2):

Try following: in touchesEnd Method:

```
[self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.5 position:ccp(yourPosition,0)]];
```